# I am trying to create a "0" record in SQL where a certain date does not exist, any ideas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to create a new record to the dataset below, what I am trying to do is create a record that is equal to the [snap] date if one already does not exist. In this new record the RPT_PRD is the same as snap date and [Estimate to Completion] and [Actual Cost of Work Performed] is set to 0.

For example, the data set will have a new record as followed:

```
PRJ_DWID, SNAP_DWID, PRJ_ELEMENT_DWID, RPT_PRD, SNAP, Estimate to completion, Actual Cost of Work Performed
 
1032, 730, 1010985, 2022-01-01, 2022-01-01, 0 , 0
```

I was able to get it to work via a CTE query and Union, but I am trying to do it stricly with a join and the query below.

```
        SELECT  Project.PRJ_DWID
            ,   Project.SNAP_DWID
            ,   Project.PRJ_ELMT_DWID
            ,   CONVERT(date,DIM_PRD.PRD_BEG_DT) AS [RPT_PRD]
            ,   CONVERT(date, REPLACE(DIM_SNAP.EFF_PRD, N'-', N' 1, 20')) AS SNAP
            ,   Project.FCST_RAW_COST AS [Estimate to Completion]
            ,   Project.ACCTD_RAW_COST AS [Actual Cost of Work Performed]
        FROM DataTable.Project
            INNER JOIN DataTable.DIM_SNAP
                ON Project.SNAP_DWID = DIM_SNAP.DWID
            INNER JOIN DataTable.DIM_PRD
                ON Project.PRD_DWID = DIM_PRD.DWID
        WHERE Project.SNAP_DWID = '730' AND Project.PRJ_DWID = '1032' AND CONVERT(date,DIM_PRD.PRD_BEG_DT) LIKE '%2022%' AND Project.PRJ_ELMT_DWID = '1010985'
```

[Current Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eEOQ.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL8FC.png)

Comment: I'm guessing you need a `LEFT JOIN` somewhere; I'm not really clear on what you are actually after here. The query you have given us isn't valid either; you have `OUTER JOIN`, but don't denote if it's a `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL` `OUTER JOIN`, you don't close the parenthesis, and there is no `ON` clause for said `{something} OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry if it is not clear, but for the LEFT outer join statement, what can I write to create a new record. And how can I join on to insert the new record into my query.

Comment: You would need to create a dataset of all the rows you require, and then `LEFT JOIN` from that. This is difficult to suggest when we don't have sample data; only the incorrect data, and that's as an image (so not consumable).

Comment: You need a calendar table showing all dates, then left join everything else to that

Comment: `CONVERT(date,DIM_PRD.PRD_BEG_DT) LIKE '%2022%' ` Bad habits are easy to learn and difficult to break. See [dating responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - read the entire thing.